# non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member error when assigning member function to vector

Tags: c++

Im trying to add a member function of Player Class to a vector of functions.

This is the vector of functions that require a Keyboard::Key as parameter.

```
vector<function<void(Keyboard::Key)>> KeyEvent;
```

Then i have the Players implementation

```
Player::Player() {
    KeyEvent.push_back(OnKey); //error: non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
}

void Player::OnKey(Keyboard::Key key) {
    //do something with key...
}
```

I have other instances where something code similair works fine, but not with member functions.

```
vector<function<void()>> UpdateEvent;

UpdateEvent.push_back(HandleInputUpdate);

void HandleInputUpdate() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pressedKeys.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t e = 0; e < KeyEvent.size(); e++) {
            KeyEvent[e](pressedKeys[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add an a member function to this vector and if not, how could I create something similair? I am very new to C++ and I created the vector so I could replicate C# Actions. This is how far i have come until I ran into problems. This is an early concept as I still need to add a way to remove functions from the vector.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to state this, using &Onkey will unfortunately just give another error:
'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnKey` is a non-static member function of `Player` and thus requires an instance of `Player` to be called on. Even if you got the pointer-to-member-function syntax right, you'd still have that exact problem, because there is no automatic binding; in other words, the instance pointed to by `this` is *not* automatically used to produce a callable object usable as a `std::function<void(Keyboard::Key)>`.

A very easy way to achieve what you want to do here is to use a lambda:

```
KeyEvent.push_back([this](auto key) { OnKey(key); });
```

The `OnKey(key);` call in the function is equivalent to `this->OnKey(key);`.

---

A more complicated (in my opinion) way would be to use `std::bind`:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
KeyEvent.push_back(std::bind(&Player::OnKey, this, _1));
```

Generally speaking, with lambdas and `std::function` in modern C++, use cases for pointers to member functions have become extremely rare.

Answer (score 0):

UsePlayer::OnKey, (merely having OnKey or even &OnKkey) is insufficient for the pointer-to-member situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add an a member function to this vector

No. Non-static member function pointers are quite a bit different than non-member function pointers and static member function pointers.

> and if not, how could I create something similair?

Use a lambda expression. In the lambda expression, make sure to capture the `this` pointer and use it in the function call.

```
KeyEvent.push_back([this](Keyboard::Key key) {this->OnKey(key);});
```

Comment: I think there's a bug: The lambda function shouldn't return anything.